# What are spherically symmetric function?

Tags: group-theory, information-theory, symmetry

I recently came accross a line in a paper which talked about chosing

> Spherically symmetric real valued function (evaluated through its
>   spherical harmonics power spectrum)

What does this mean? Looking on the internet results in answers related to Quantum physics whereas I am looking for a more general definition.

[Opening the Black Box of Deep Neural Networks via Information](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00810)
Page 8, Para 2, Line 1 & 2

Comment: Maybe $SO(n)$ invariant

Comment: maybe this http://aurelie.boisbunon.free.fr/downloads/loisSS.pdf

Comment: $f(\theta, \phi, r) = f(\pi + \theta, \pi/2 - \phi, r)$.

Comment: I think it should be essentially what Andres says, or alternatively: $f(\theta, \phi, r)$ depends only on $r$.

Comment: That's explained in the reference cited in the paper: (Kazhdan et al, 2003) http://gfx.cs.princeton.edu/pubs/Kazhdan_2003_RIS/SGP03.pdf